# Node.js: Error ECONNRESET while piping a file

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I have this error while "piping" a file in node:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Pipe.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

Here is my code:

```
var json_file = fs.createWriteStream(jsonFile),
    processes = 0,
    read_ended_flag = false,
    converter = new Converter(params);

let read_csv_file = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);

// For each csv line, we get a json doc
converter.on('record_parsed', jsonObj => {
    processes++;

    json_file.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObj) + '\n', () => {
        processes--;

        if(read_ended_flag && processes == 0){
            json_file.end();
            callback();
        }
    });
});

converter.on('end_parsed', () => {
    read_ended_flag = true;
});

read_csv_file
    .pipe(converter);
```

I tried to catch error using [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6043) or [this](http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/node.js/27610595.html), but it still the same.
This bug only comes while working with small files ( > 100 lines ).

Is it because that the read stream is closed before writing in the new file ?

Many thanks for any tips & helps !

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution ! :)

It was due to my Converter param (csvtojson module), i put workerNum to 4, instead i have to put 1 for dealing small files.

> workerNum: Number of worker processes. The worker process will use multi-cores to help process CSV data. Set to number of Core to improve the performance of processing large csv file. Keep 1 for small csv files. Default 1.

[Here](https://devhub.io/repos/Keyang-node-csvtojson) is a complete tutorial about csvtojson module

Hope it helps others !

Comment: You cannot believe how much time you saved me. Million thanks